# Create script on package.json to run mocha tests

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai, package.json

I have an express.js application and I am trying to write a script to run mocha tests "npm run test" but I am getting an error message that "." is not recocnized.
This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "node-js-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Sample project NodeJS",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --watch-extensions js \"{,!(node_modules)/**/}*.test.js\" "
  },
  "keywords": [
    "API",
    "Nodejs"
  ],
  "license": "",
  "dependencies": {
      "body-parser": "^1.19.2",
      "express": "^4.17.1",
      "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
      "chai": "^4.2.0",
      "mocha": "^7.0.1"
  }
}
```

Getting this error:

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

The idea is to use "npm run test" and run all the files that ends with ".test.js" inside "test" folder

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your tests are in the `./test` directory at the root of your project, your test script should be:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha"
}
```

You should not be in `./node_modules/`

If you want to run mocha at the command line, you can run `npx mocha`. The docs in mocha haven't been updated since `npx` was added to `npm`.